# Silverlight DataGrid changes between version 3 and 4

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

Does anyone have a list of changes from Silverlight 3 DataGrid to Silverlight 4 DataGrid?

Best Regards,
Jesper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column resizing, mouse wheel support. Here's a couple of links.

[DataGrid Enhancements](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/datagrid-enhancements/)

[Silverlight 4 Rough Notes: Data Grid Enhancements](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/11/18/silverlight-4-rough-notes-data-grid-enhancements.aspx)

From [Ensuring That Your Silverlight Applications Work with Silverlight 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645049(VS.95).aspx):

> DataGridCell objects and automation
>   focus when currency changes in the
>   DataGrid
>
> DataGridCell objects in
>   Silverlight 4 receive automation focus
>   when currency changes in the DataGrid,
>   rather than focus remaining on the
>   DataGrid itself.
>
> Some more detail: UI Automation
>   clients originally did not get
>   information about the currently
>   focused cell because DataGridCell
>   objects are not focusable controls
>   (attempted Focus returns false). This
>   has not changed. DataGridCell objects
>   are still not focusable in UI.
>   However, for Silverlight 4 they will
>   receive automation focus when DataGrid
>   currency changes. Now when you tab
>   into a DataGrid and use the ARROW keys
>   to change currency, automation focus
>   will move to the individual cell peers
>   so that UI Automation clients can
>   receive specific automation property
>   information for the cells. Previously,
>   automation focus remained on the
>   DataGrid; this remains as the
>   Silverlight 3 behavior, based on the
>   Silverlight 3
>   System.Windows.Controls.Data.dll.